# Infinite loop to output all values from an array

Tags: javascript

From the function django I return JSON to JS

```
 paymentparking = paidparking.objects.filter(expirationdate__range=(startdate, enddate)).values('expirationdate','price')
    return JsonResponse({'result': list(paymentparking)})
```

Here I need to get all the expirationdate values. How can this be done and how can the cycle be organized?

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "statistics",
    data: {
      'startdate': finalDateStrStart,'enddate': finalDateStrEnd,
    },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success:function (data) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
                 console.log(data.result[i].expirationdate)
        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: use the size of the result vector and loop over it.  will each result have an expirationdate -- you may want to do a null check there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe do something like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    if(data.result) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
            console.log(data.result[i].expirationdate)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.map()` to iterate over elements and return an array of expirationdate.

```
success: function (data) {
  data?.result && data.result.map(obj => console.log(obj.expirationdate));
}
```

Comment: This is again an array, and I need to output all the elements from the same array

Comment: use console.log() to output instead of returning, updated the above code